# Checking the class type of a mock object

Tags: mocking, mockito, instanceof

I'm testing a method that gets an object and checks if that object is an instance of a class that is stored as instance variable. So far no problem.

But in the test I have to use mocks and one of these mocks is the object that is passed on to that method. And now, it becomes tricky. Let's see the code (I summed up the code in this test):

```
Class<AdapterEvent> clazz = AdapterEvent.class;
AdapterEvent adapterEvent = Mockito.mock(AdapterEvent.class);
    
Assert.assertTrue(adapterEvent.getClass().equals(clazz));
Assert.assertTrue(adapterEvent.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz));
```

Well, this test actually fails. Does anyone know why? Does somebody has an idea how I could solve this problem by still using a mock like in the test? Is there maybe another way of comparing objects to a specific class.

Comment: You might want to accept one of the answer below(if one is correct).

Answer (score 11):

Your first assertion will *never* be true - Mockito mocks are a whole new class, so a simple `equals()` will never work. By the way, for tests like this you'll get a far more useful failure message if you use `Assert.assertEquals()`, where the first argument is the expected result; e.g.:

```
Assert.assertEquals(clazz, adapterEvent.getClass());
```

Your second assertion *would* be correct, but you've mixed up the direction of `isAssignableFrom()` (easily done, the JavaDoc is mighty confusing) - flip it around and you're golden:

```
Assert.assertTrue(clazz.isAssignableFrom(adapterEvent.getClass()));
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a new method [getMockedType](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getMockedType()) in Mockito 2.0.0 that returns the class originally passed into `Mockito.mock(Class)`.  I would recommend using this method because the `getSuperClass()` technique doesn't work in all cases.

```
MockingDetails mockingDetails = Mockito.mockingDetails(mockObj);
Class<?> cls = mockingDetails.getMockedType();
```

Comment: this syntax has changed, now one should use something like that:
``Mockito.mockingDetails(mockObj).getMockCreationSettings().getTypeToMock()``

Answer (score 3):

I would think that instanceof would work the way you want it to:

```
Assert.assertTrue(adapterEvent instanceof AdapterEvent);
```

Are you sure you should even be testing for this?  Not knowing what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to say but I think this test might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Mocked class is subclassed from your original class, so just check the superclass, like this:

Assert.assertTrue(adapterEvent.getClass().getSuperclass().equals(clazz));

Comment: even better is to use `Assert.assertEquals(clazz, adapterEvent.getClass().getSuperclass());`. Then you'll get a more useful error message when the test fails.

Answer (score 1):

To test an object has returned the instance of a class in C# you are expecting then do the following

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(adapterEvent, typeof(AdapterEvent));
```

Comment: Though this answer might perhaps solve the question, always add explanation.