# getClass of mockito mock

Tags: java, mockito

I need to get the bean-name of instances. So I built (simplified):

```
  public String getName(Object instance) {
      return uncapitalize(instance.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
```

What happens during tests is that a `mock(MyInstance.class)` enters this method. Instead of `"myInstance"`, I then get `"testClassName$$MyInstance$$EnhancerByMockito$$...."`

Is it somehow possible to detect that the instance is a mock instance and get the "real" type?

Comment: I'd try walking up the chain of superclasses/superinterfaces until you find one whose name doesn't contain "EnhancerByMockito".

Comment: Useful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14871765/3788176

Comment: Thanks, Andy, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Andy Turner, I now use this:

```
 static final String ENHANCER = "$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$";

 static Class<? extends Object> typeOf(Object instance) {
   Class<? extends Object> type = instance.getClass();
   while(type.getSimpleName().contains(ENHANCER)) {
     type = type.getSuperclass();
   }

   return type;
 }
```

Comment: Update : won't work with Mockito 2.x, in that case use `static final String ENHANCER = "$MockitoMock$";`